# UWP Encode WriteableBitmap to JPEG byte array

Tags: uwp, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

I'm trying to encode WriteableBitmap to JPEG byte array. But actually I found examples with the SaveJpeg method which does not exist now.
So I tried the ToStreamAsJpeg method but this method does not work. With the step by step I don't get out of it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I solved my issue with the following method:

```
private async Task<byte[]> EncodeJpeg(WriteableBitmap bmp)
{
    SoftwareBitmap soft = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(bmp.PixelBuffer, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight);
    byte[] array = null;

    using (var ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, ms);
        encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(soft);

        try
        {
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch { }

        array = new byte[ms.Size];
        await ms.ReadAsync(array.AsBuffer(), (uint)ms.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Also, if you have a best implementation... ;-)